# Problem with 404 Page on Mac

Tags: browser, safari, dynamic-dns

I have installed DNS Updater from DynDNS and now a have a "custom" not found page in Safari!

`http://searchassist.teoma.com`

How can I remove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable DynDNS Internet guide from DynDNS options -> Advanced